# SQL UNION changes values of a table

Tags: sql, teradata, union, union-all

I'm using Teradata. Trying to understand a very strange thing.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    TYPE,
    '' AS SUB_TYPE
FROM Table_A
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID,
    TYPE,
    SUB_TYPE
FROM TABLE_B
```

Somehow, valid values of Table B become blank in the result.

| ID | TYPE | SUB_YPE | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A type from table A |  | correct, empty string as a constant |
| 2 | A type from table B |  | incorrect, sub type has a value in B |
| 3 | Another type from table B | null | correct, sub type is null in B |

But when I exchange query 1 and 2, everything works fine.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    TYPE,
    SUB_TYPE
FROM TABLE_B
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID,
    TYPE,
    '' AS SUB_TYPE
FROM Table_A
```

| ID | TYPE | SUB_TYPE | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A type from table B | A sub type from table B | correct |
| 3 | Another type from table B | null | correct |
| 1 | A type from table A |  | correct |

This is bizarre, can anyone help explain?

Comment: You should show how is the data in every table. In any case why would you do an union all without any condition? You should get repeated rows by ids

Comment: @LeandroBardelli

The queries are simplified to demonstrate the problem - In the actual query I do have WHERE clauses that target a specific list of IDs and the current snapshot of the tables.

UNION ALL should be fine and probably faster than UNION. Table A and B store different sets of IDs (A for individual customers and B for entity customers) so will not have duplicates.

Comment: The first Select determines the data type, you probably have to `CAST('' AS VARCHAR(xx))` to match the column from the 2nd table.

Comment: @dnoeth I see, thanks. If my understanding is correct, the 1st query implies CHAR(0), so the 2nd query turns all VARCHAR(xx) values into CHAR(0) too - Interesting.

Comment: Yes, `select type('')` returns `VARCHAR(0) CHARACTER SET UNICODE`